# How do I check if text in textarea contains a particular word?

Tags: regex, textarea

I am having a text like this

> this is my sample
>   text message
>   for validation

I want a single REGEX to find whether that message contains a particular word.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear from your question that you have no understanding of regular expressions. **However**, you do seem to know where to use them. Give these resources a look.

### Resources:

[Syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

[Tester and Library](http://regexlib.com/)

Comment: i want use in validation rules

Comment: @Mubarak, what do you mean by 'validation rules'? You have not tags as to the language you are working with.